# I am getting this error when trying test connection to websphere server 8.5

Tags: sql-server, websphere

The error coming out of test connection is:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset ClientConnectionId:8ffbbfac-bddc-4b02-97e0-46227bd4b03a
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:651)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:708)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:49)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:192)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:407)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.av.i(av.java:45)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:460 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.av.a(av.java:637)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:461 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.av.startHandshake(av.java:1020)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:461 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
[3/30/22 15:06:36:461 IST] 0000006f SystemErr     R     ... 104 more
[3/30/22 15:06:46:738 IST] 000000de SystemErr     R java.sql.SQLException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Connection reset ClientConnectionId:cc6ab39e-6ec0-4688-a15f-359067e2215f". DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0
[3/30/22 15:06:46:738 IST] 000000de SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1668)
[3/30/22 15:06:46:739 IST] 000000de SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
[3/30/22 15:06:46:739 IST] 000000de SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1324)
[3/30/22 15:06:46:739 IST] 000000de SystemErr     R     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServe
```

The database is Microsoft SQLServer.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the details of the datasource you're testing someone can help.

Comment: The details of the datasource, not the exception.  How is the DS configured?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kRkJCAU/database-connection-fails-with-dsra0010e-sql-state-08s01-exception-in-websphere-application-server?language=en_US, and **many** other sites if  you google your error code.